# Is it normal for House session videos to error, and are there alternative websites that host them?

Tags: united-states, congress, legislative-process, house-of-representatives

I've been looking for the House of Representatives legislative session video on [May 23](http://houselive.gov/ViewPublisherRSS.php?view_id=2), but when I try to see it [I get an error](http://houselive.gov/MediaPlayer.php?view_id=2&clip_id=12102):

> The system was unable to find the content that you requested. The content may be in the process of transferring to a distribution server. Please try again later.

I find this rather eyebrow-raising because the very reason I went to see these videos is that I heard about some interesting news on that day, and yet it is somehow precisely May 22 and 23 that are unavailable, **not** later or earlier sessions. May 21, 24, 25, etc. load just fine.

So, my questions are:

1. Is this a normal occurrence, and can I actually expect these videos to be put up again later?
2. Are there any alternative sites where I can find videos of particular legislative sessions?

Comment: What is this "interesting news", and is it sufficient to make someone delete a file? The site you point at is managed by the Clerk of the House of Representatives, so if that was done without her authorisation it would probably be a crime. Have you tried emailing any of the support addresses at the bottom of this page? http://clerk.house.gov/about/duties.aspx ? Hanlon's Razor would seem to apply here: never attribute to malice that which can be adequately explained by stupidity.

Comment: @PaulJohnson: I'd rather not spread potentially-misleading information/rumors until I get a chance to see the video myself, so I won't go in that direction here. But no, I haven't emailed them -- I didn't even realize who was responsible or what their email was. If I email them and hear back I'll report back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While this is probably a webserver issue, and it seems not a very common one (or one that gets fixed) as a quick sample did not find any other days on which the video wasn't available.

However, c-span also has video for that day:

[2018-05-23](https://www.c-span.org/congress/?date=2018-05-23)

They divide it up into more manageable parts, so you don't need to go searching through 9 hours of video.

Comment: +1 thank you a ton for the C-SPAN video! It seems that the specific amendments I was interested in had no oral discussions or mentions at all, so there was nothing for them to hide; I guess that means it must be a webserver issue.